# Unity3d move object with some force

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools, rigid-bodies

This is what i try to achieve in 2D:

- A GameObject
- A button
- A scene

1) I push the button 
2) The GameObject comes in from the side like someone are throwing the GameObject into the scene meaning it have some speed that blends off and stop

I know i need to use RigidBody2d but i do not get it to work. Could someone please give me a hint how to solve this?

Comment: See [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/601175/rigidbody2daddforce-doesnt-work.html)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the problem? "I know i need to use RigidBody2d but i do not get it to work" doesn't really tell us what's happening.

Comment: Elaborate your issue more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You may use free libraries like iTween that allow you to move objects in 3d or 2d space. With iTween making it appear "outside" the screen and move while slowing down to a certain point is easy. Or do you want to use physics for that?